# How to implement bundling and minification in web forms with asp.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

Is it possible to implement bundling and minification feature in a asp.net web forms application without changing the .net framework version? If yes what should be done? Currently the .net framework that my asp.net application using is 2.0.XXXX

> **Note: I want to do this in .net 2.0.XXXX only**

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) explains how.

Comment: @anmarti i have already gone through that link. In that link it says .net framework 4.5. What i am asking is to implement in .net 2.0

Comment: @KashifKhan B&M was introduced in .NET 4.5. But this [article by Igor](http://igorzelmanovich.blogspot.in/2012/09/using-aspnet-bundling-and-minification.html) shows how B&M can be applied in .NET 4.0. I don't know whether the assemblies/nuget packages used in this article are compatible with .NET 2.0 or not. But you may try this way.